# epoll and negative errno value

Tags: c++, unix, epoll

I have ERROR_OUT function, which uses vfprintf inside to log errors in console. When im trying to log some epoll errors with this function `ERROR_OUT(L_NOTICE, "Epoll error: %d", errno);` ,  i'm getting strange output sometimes:

```
Epoll error: -1079274856
```

I'm using it after `epoll_wait` and `epoll_ctl` only and it's beeing called only in case of negative return value.

Code of ERROR_OUT:

```
void ERROR_OUT(int level, char *template, ...){           
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, template);

    if ( level <= verbosity ){
                if (output_handler == NULL){
                        vfprintf(stderr, template, ap);
                }else{
                        (*output_handler)(level, template, ap);
                }
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Code of output handler:

```
void log_both(int level, const char *fmt, ...){
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, fmt);   
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, argp);
    printf("\n");
    if (globalArgs.db_verbosity >= level)
        globalArgs.db_log->log_error(format(fmt, argp));
    va_end(argp);
}
```

Comment: IS this really C++ ? template is a reserve keyword. And where do you get the errno exactly ?

Comment: Any function call can change the value of `errno`, so if you do anything between the call to `epoll_*` and `ERROR_OUT()` the result would be undefined. Can you show us these calls?

Comment: Add your calls to `epoll_wait` and `epoll_ctl` with surrounding code.

Comment: You pass a `va_list` in the call to `log_both` via `*output_handler` and wrap that `va_list` in the `va_list` named `argp`. So you actually pass a `va_list` that contains a `va_list` to `vfprintf` as third argument which expects a decimal due to `%d` to be the first element in the `va_list`. It should therefore be `void log_both(int level, const char *fmt, va_list argp){}` with `va_list argp;`, `va_start(argp, fmt);` and `va_end(argp);` removed from the function body.

Comment: @rodrigo, yes i found at least ``gettimeofday(2)`` between ``epoll_wait`` and ``ERROR_OUT``. I'll check the behavior after removing it, but seems like this may be a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a `va_list` in the call to `log_both` via `*output_handler` and wrap that `va_list` in the `va_list` named `argp`.

So you actually pass a `va_list` that contains a `va_list` to `vfprintf` as third argument which expects a decimal due to `%d` to be the first element in the `va_list`.

It should therefore be `void log_both(int level, const char *fmt, va_list argp){}` with `va_list argp;`, `va_start(argp, fmt);` and `va_end(argp);` removed from the function body.

```
void log_both(int level, const char *fmt, va_list argp){
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, argp);
    printf("\n");
    if (globalArgs.db_verbosity >= level)
        globalArgs.db_log->log_error(format(fmt, argp));
}
```